# PHP & SQL LEFT JOIN when i echo it display only content with id 1

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, left-join

So basically, I have 2 tables 
first table called "brand" and it contains columns "brand_id", "brand_name"
Then I have a second table called "products" that contains many columns but the most important is "product_brand"
Brand table:
[image]

Product table:
[image]

When i use this code

```
$brand = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT products.*,brand.brand_name FROM products LEFT JOIN brand ON products.product_brand = brand.brand_id")  or die(mysqli_errno($conn). '-'. mysqli_error($conn));
```

then i try to echo it like this `<?php echo $znacka['brand_name']; ?>`

When i do that it only display the first brand on every product.

Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: Please add some more code. For instance how you file the array `znacka`

Comment: The query is good. If a product always has a brand, you might change it to an inner join, but with a left join it should work too. I'm afraid the bug might be in the PHP code, so please show the code that outputs the information too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all data from both table then please remove **left**.
You have to apply inner join for this.

```
$brand = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT products.*,brand.brand_name FROM products JOIN brand ON products.product_brand = brand.brand_id")  or die(mysqli_errno($conn). '-'. mysqli_error($conn));
```

Now you can use `$znacka['brand_name']`.